# How to use AOS inangular 7/8?

Tags: angular

Import inn both arrays

```
"styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "node_modules/@coreui/icons/css/coreui-icons.css",
              "node_modules/flag-icon-css/css/flag-icon.css",
              "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
              "node_modules/simple-line-icons/css/simple-line-icons.css",
              "src/scss/style.scss",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "/node_modules/aos/dist/aos.css"
            ],
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": [
                "./node_modules"
              ]
            },
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js",
              "/node_modules/aos/dist/aos.js"
            ]
```

And also in component file

```
import * as AOS from 'aos';
ngOnInit(){
AOS.init();
}
```

And in html file I used like this

```
<div class="jd1 mb-40">
  <div class="container" data-aos="fade-right">
    <img src="../../../assets/dummy/wae.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

but still not working.Help me what mistake have I made or something new I can use when page is scrolling.

Comment: Can you try adding the script in index.html?

Comment: ```<script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.js"></script> and <link href="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">```
added both but still the same

Comment: instead of importing in the component you can use `declare let AOS: any`. Can you try it?

Comment: Sry errors there i used but.

Comment: What most of the website use, if you can name different then AOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
declare let AOS: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  constructor() {
    console.log(AOS); // loaded script
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    AOS.init();
  }
}
```

in Index.html,

```
<link href="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.js"></script>
```

That worked for me.